# Extraer información de base de datos a un formulario PHP con un botón radio

Tags: php, html

Tengo una tabla en la BD y quiero traer la información a un formulario. Consigo extraer la info excepto la de los botones radio. Cómo debería hacerlo?
Así es como lo tengo pero no me funciona.. me quedan sin marcar ninguno de los botones radio.

```
echo "<label> Edad</label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."'> <br>";
```

Resuelto:

```
<?php 
   echo "<p> Edad </p>"; 
   if($resultado["edad"] != "Si"){ 
       echo "<label>No</label><input type='radio' name='edad'value='".$resultado["edad"]."' checked> <br>"; 
       echo "<label> Si </label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."'> <br>"; 
   }else{ 
       echo "<label> Si </label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."' checked> <br>"; 
       echo "<label>No</label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."'> <br>";' 
   }
?>
```

Comment: Que valor te devuelve edad? @Ara

Comment: Devuelve texto @WalterCordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los radio buttons solo pueden marcarse con el atributo [checked](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp), esto podría funcionarte:

```
<label> Edad</label>
<?php 
if($resultado["edad"] != ""){
    echo "<label> Edad</label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."' checked> <br>";
}else{
    echo "<label> Edad</label><input type='radio' name='edad' value=''> <br>";
}
?>
```

Lo que estamos validando en este código es que el valor venga vació, ya como lo mencionaste en los comentarios el valor que retorna `$resultado["edad"]` es un string por lo que la lógica me dice que si insertaste un dato debería mostrarse con un check, de lo contrario dejarlo vació.

Como recomendación, cuando uses radio buttons es una mala practica guardarlo como texto, en todo caso si es un check lo que harás en tu formulario mejor envía un entero 1 por ejemplo y 0 por default, así tendrías esta lógica: 1 activo, 0 inactivo

Comment: Gracias, esto se aproxima más pero así solo me sale una opción

Comment: Bueno en este caso creo que deberías ampliar tu pregunta y mostrar más código, ya que según tu parámetro y la cuestión actual esto es todo lo que podrías hacer. Si necesitas mostrar más opciones sé más especifica

Comment: lo conseguí así, gracias!!  'echo "<h1> Edad </h1>";
            if($resultado["edad"] != "Si"){
                echo "<label>No</label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."' checked> <br>";
                echo "<label> Si </label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."'> <br>";
            }else{
                echo "<label> Si </label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."' checked> <br>";
                echo "<label>No</label><input type='radio' name='edad' value='".$resultado["edad"]."'> <br>";'
}

Comment: Excelente @Ara, edita tu pregunta para que sirva a la comunidad y vota por la respuesta que te sirvio. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer algo así en tu formulario:

```
<label> Edad</label>
<input type='radio' name='edad' value='<?php echo $resultado["edad"]?>' > <br>
```

Comment: Eso lo probé en el html pero no me funciona. Lo que hice sí me funciona en todo excepto en los botones radio

Comment: En ese caso puede que tu desde el back tu haya un error, intenta parsear la variable a int antes de enviarla o antes de renderizarla.